# Infragistics XamDataGrid WPF MVVM SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, infragistics, selectionchanged, xamdatagrid

We are implementing a MVVM architecture in our WPF application. We want to use the Infragistics XamDataGrid but kind of lost about implementing the selection changed event on the view model layer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

We need a solution urgently!!!

Anshuman Chakravarty
Humana Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the above issue. I did it in a very simple way.

1. Bind the ActiveCell property of the XamGrid to an object type property in the VM.
2. In the setter of the property, call a method and pass the object.
3. Inside the method, cast the object to Infragictics.Windows.Cell type variable.
4. Use the Infragistics.Windows.Cell object's Record.Index to find the Selected Index.
5. Using that index, find the row selected from the original collection/data source to which the xamdatagrid was binded.

*Simple, but effective!!!*

Comment: This works, but now your ViewModel is coupled to the View instead of the other way around. If you want to change your control library to another third party library, or even your own custom control, you've got to change the ViewModel, which is precisely what you shouldn't have to do...

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your comment, but I don't think my VM is coupled with the V. The object is not aware of where's it coming from and from there on, I'm doing the processing at the collection at the VM and have nothing to do with the View. View is, in fact coupled to my VM to the property I mentioned above!!!

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you have a property in your ViewModel that you bind to the View.  When the active cell on the view changes, that calls a setter in the ViewModel.  That setter casts to an Infragistics.Windows.Cell type.  Now, change your view to use a SyncFusion grid.  Will your ViewModel still work?  If not, then it's coupled to the View.

Answer (score 4):

For Infragistic v11.2 XamlDataGrid has property called **ActiveDataItem** that represent current dataitem bound to the row.

What you can do is create property in your ViewModel and Bind that to ActiveDataItem of XamlDataGrid as Below and observe the changes as below.

```
<igDataPresenter:XamDataGrid ActiveDataItem="{Binding ActiveItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

**My Scenario**:
I wanted to fire command on my dataItem bound to individual grid row on doubleclick on individual rows, Below xaml code is working for me,

```
        <igDataPresenter:XamDataGrid x:Name="DemoGrid" 
                    DataSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}"
        >
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=igDataPresenter:XamDataGrid}, Path=ActiveDataItem.ViewCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>

        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

here are some other events by xamdatagrid.

```
SelectedItemsChanged
SelectedItemsChanging

RecordActivating
RecordActivated
```

these might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jodha. But, these events would work fine for code behind of xaml file. I want to implement the event handlers at the view-model layer. Any one with an example of attached behavior?

Comment: take a look at this http://community.infragistics.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.23.52.90/XamDataGrid_5F00_Behaviors.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to be able to bind the selected items using MVVM then I would recommend using a behavior to accomplish this.  Devin Rader wrote a [blog post](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2011/06/01/using-behaviors-to-synchronize-selected-items-of-infragistics-silverlight-controls-to-a-viewmodel.aspx) that covers synchronizing values between a view model for and the UI for selection and you may be able to use something similar to know when the selection has changed within your view model.

Let me know if you have any questions with this matter.

Answer (score -2):

I've never used the data grid that you're asking about but you can bet it works the same as everything else.

in the ViewModel that you're binding the view to there will be a property called SelectedItem or something to that effect.

```
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

in the xaml you can probably bind the grids Selected property to that dependency property.

```
<XamDataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Items} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. But this looks more like binding just the SelectedItem property. I already implemented that. I need to implement Commanding (Event Handling Delegation) for SelectionChange. This is not working in this XAMDataGrid

Comment: Hi Andy, when I tried create the DependencyProperty and use it in the XAMDataGrid, I got the following error:
Error 1 The property 'SelectedItem' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter'. Line 94 Position 27.

Comment: xamDataGrid does not contain a SelectedItem property